# Bokeh - Can we change font of tab title and reduce width/height of the tabs

Tags: python, widget, bokeh

Can we change the font-family of text on tab titles. (i.e. of 'circle' and 'line'? Also wanted to know if we can change the height/width of these tabs. Since I have around 10 tabs and it's taking a lot of space.

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import Panel, Tabs
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_file("slider.html")

p1 = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p1.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], size=20, color="navy", alpha=0.5)
tab1 = Panel(child=p1, title="circle")
p2 = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p2.line([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], line_width=3, color="navy", alpha=0.5)
tab2 = Panel(child=p2, title="line") 
tabs = Tabs(tabs=[ tab1, tab2 ])
show(tabs)
```

[image]

Comment: in [documentation about Panel/Tabs](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/widgets.panels.html), we can see in JSON Prototypes that there is a "css_classes": [] for these elements. Maybe you can set a font to the title and adapt height of tabs via custom css code, in [embbeded html](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html) or via a [template](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#directory-format)